# Attach Assembly to Word 2010 document

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, word-2010

I have found a solution to attach managed code (AKA 'Assembly') created from VSTO 2010 to a Word 2010 document from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268877.aspx)

I have followed all the steps, but I didn't find the `.application` file in the project debug folder. I assumed that it was the `.vsto` file.  However, when I added properties as instructed in the link mentioned above, and closed and reopened the document I'm getting an error message saying that the Assembly can not be found or it can not be loaded.

Has anyone run into this previously?  What am I missing?

Comment: The document you're linking to is for Office 2003, try using [these instructions for VS 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb772091(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have added the _AssemblyLocation and _AssemblyName in custom property in document suggested in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268877.aspx)  and now its working fine...